# Why is IE8 not showing my <img> wrapped in a <h1> and <a> tag?

Tags: image, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, header

Since I have this problem third time in row I need to know this:

Why is IE8 not showing the logo in the top left of [this site](http://starflower.at/sma/test-the-best/)??

The image is wrapped in a header > h1 > a

This is so strange, since apparently only IE8 has this problem!

Comment: IMG { max-width: 100%; } is causing it.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `max-width: 100%` in the CSS style for the img tag, or clear it for that specific element.

Comment: Why?  I have a similar problem, but this answer doesn't help me without explanation as to why it helps